# Minion not picking up multiple pillar sources

Tags: salt-stack

I have a problem where a minion isn't picking up both sources of pillar information, but instead only picking up to the last source referred to. For an example the following is my /srv/pillar/top.sls:

```
base:
  'client.id':
    - users.support
    - users.dev
```

The content of my /srv/pillar/users/support.sls is as follows:

```
users:
  - name: supportname
    fullname: Name of Support user
    uid: 1001
    groups:
      - sudo
      - support
```

The content of my /srv/pillar/users/dev.sls is as follows:

```
users:
  - name: devname
    fullname: Name of Dev user
    uid: 1002
    groups:
      - dev
```

When calling `salt 'client.id' pillar.items` it will only show the last specified pillar (for this example, only dev information would be shown). If I was to switch the order the opposite content is shown. I'm really stumped as to what could be causing this.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, SaltStack has a limited merging strategy for pillars [1]. In your case, the `users` key is defined as a list. Lists can't be merged in pillars, so the last parsed pillar wins. That's what you see.

However, dicts are merged, provided the keys are different. You may use this for your need:

/srv/pillar/users/support.sls:

```
users:
  supportname:
    fullname: Name of Support user
    uid: 1001
    groups:
      - sudo
      - support
```

/srv/pillar/users/dev.sls:

```
users:
  devname:
    fullname: Name of Dev user
    uid: 1002
    groups:
      - dev
```

You'll end with a `users` dictionary containing two entries: `supportname` and `devname`. You can then loop on it with `for username, userdef in salt['pillar.get']('users', {}).iteritems()`, for example.

[1] https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/pillar/#pillar-namespace-merges

Comment: Thank you so much. There's so much documentation for Salt sometimes it can be difficult to find the very specific bit you need.